# Provisioning profile failed qualification in adhoc distribution?

Tags: ios, xcode11

I am trying to distribute iOS app through adhoc. Target iOS version is 11.0 and xcode version is 11.5. And I am using macOS Catalina version 10.15.5. I can build the version to simulator but when I try to distribute the application I am getting the error. And also I am using iCloud documents in this project.

Tried to distribute with xcode 12 beta, but getting the same error.